# Is there a well known algorithm to find self-overlaps within a tolerance distance for linestrings/polygonal chains?

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, boost-geometry

In the following example, taking the following linestring as the input, the two sub-linestrings output I’m interested in are the two parts between C/D, the cutting lines.

[image: PastedGraphic-3.png]

It's trivially easy to do it between two distinct linestrings, but within the same one is much harder.  Is this a known problem/is there an obvious approach to this I am missing ?

Comment: I'm interested in 2D for now.  But I think a 3d/generalizable solution would be interesting for some people too.

Comment: And why is it "much harder" with the same line, compared to two distinct ones?

Comment: Because you can densify/sample a line  (Move forward a small distance, sample, etc), find the nearest point on the other line, and if that point is within a given distance, you are on one of the segment.  However, finding the nearest point on the other line doesn't make sense in the case of being on the same line.  So you'd need to cut forward or behind a certain distance and then start sampling.  I'm assuming there's a better approach.